# Cambiar resultado "[object Object]" por uno propio

Tags: javascript, json, poo, variables, objeto

El elemento `Document` si lo pones en una alert te lanza `[object HTMLDocument]` igual que el `window` que te lanza `[object Window]`

```
alert(document);  //[object HTMLDocument]
alert(window);  //[object Window]
```

pero cuando yo creo un objeto llamado p y lo pongo en una alerta me lanza [object Object]

```
var p = { string:"esto es un string" };
alert(p);// [object Object]
```

Necesito que el alert en lugar de `[object Object]` me gustaria que lanzara `[object p]`

Answer (score 3):

No estoy seguro si es el camino correcto. Pero podrias agregar la función `toString()` a tu objeto. Esto le permite a la función `alert` saber que imprimir cuando le pases tu objeto.

```js
    var p = { 
      string:"esto es un string",
      toString: () => ("Object P"),
    };
    alert(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes sobrescribir el metodo `toString`

```js
var p = {
    string: "esto es un string",
    toString: () => '[object p]'
};
alert(p);
```

`