# esconder el codigo de la funcion

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables, variables-globales, alert

Si uno crea una funcion Por decir llamada  `p`

```
function p(i){

 alert(i)
 }
```

Y nosotros en lugar de llamarla `p()` la llamamos como una variable `p` nos lanza el codigo.

```
alert(p)// lanza function p(i){ alert(i) };
```

Pero cuando yo por ejemplo pongo en la alerta la pongo un `indexOf` y lo llamo como variable se lanza `function indexOf() { [native code] }`

```
var t="hola";
alert(t.indexOf);// lanza function indexOf() { [native code] }
```

mi duda es. ¿como hago que oculte el codigo como lo hace en indexOf?
¿es posible?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *ocultar el código*? El hecho que ponga `[native code]` no significa que está *oculto*. Puedes hacer un `console.dir(t.indexOf)` y te mostrará todo el código de la función o método. Sucede que tu función no es parte del código nativo de JS, y por lo tanto se mostrará su contenido, por más complejo que sea. No puedes escribir funciones que sean parte del código nativo, así como tampoco puedes ocultar el mismo. En todo caso podrías [ofuscarlo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofuscaci%C3%B3n). Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Seria lo mismo que tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405960/cambiar-resultado-object-object-por-uno-propio/405979#405979).

Puedes sobrescribir el metodo `toString`

```js
function p(i) {
    alert(i)
}
p.toString = () => 'function p(i) { [private code] }';

alert(p);
```

Comment: gracias No pense que tambien se podria hacer haci